# Inverting a fraction

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm doing a complex analysis question and it is as follows

> $$\int\limits_{c}\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}dz$$

Using Maclaurin Series I simplified this expression upto this point:

> $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(e^z-1)} = \frac{1}{z^2+\frac{z^3}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{3!}+ \cdots}$$

To use the residue theorem I need to get $z^{-1}$ terms. Some guy at my class inverted (flipped) this. Can I have a little guidance how to get the $z^{-1}$ from this? :)

This is the flipped version of this fraction I found:

> $$\frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-\left(\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{4!}\right)+\left(\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{4!}+\cdots\right)+\cdots\right)$$

Is this correct? Then how to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(z)=\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)\left(1+\frac z2+\frac{z^2}6+\cdots\right)^{-1}\\
=\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)\left(1-(\frac z2+\frac{z^2}6+\cdots)+(\frac z2+\frac{z^2}6+\cdots)^2-\cdots\right)\\
=z^{-2}(1-\frac z2+\frac {z^2}{12}+...)$$

Comment: Now this is what I wanted! How to solve this $(-1)$ power?

Comment: Expand the last expression.

Comment: Can you give me a little hint on how to expand a negative powered expression?

Answer (score 1):

There is no $z^{-1}$ term.  You should be able to show that $\lim_{z\to 0} z^2\frac 1{z(e^z-1)}$ is finite, so your integrand has a second order pole.

Comment: There is one isn't it?

Comment: Yes, see WA for example. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2o0PG.png